Mock HTTP Requests in Development Mode
I'm currently working on a project using React and Axios for making HTTP requests. on local dev environment i want to mock these requests to avoid hitting the actual APIs. I have set up some conditional logic to check if the code is running in development mode, if true it mocks the requests
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  // Mocking Axios in development mode
  axios.interceptors.request.use(request => {
    if (request.url === '/api/data') {
      return Promise.resolve({ data: 'mock data' });
    }
    return request;
  });
}

while this works I want a cleaner and more maintainable solution to keep the mocking logic separate from the main application code.
I tried using Axios interceptors to mock requests based on the NODE_ENV environment variable. This works but i have to check for each request's path and it makes the code messy. i was looking for a solution to either keep all this out of my production app's code.

You can use axios-mock-adapter that allows to easily mock requests. Below example using Vite, React and jsonplaceholder. Check the environment by import.meta.env.MODE === 'development', then setup the mocks in the entry file main.tsx.
App.tsx:
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { axiosInstance } from './axiosInstance';

function App() {
  const [todo, setTodo] = useState<{ title: string }>();
  const [user, setUser] = useState<{ username: string }>();
  useEffect(() => {
    axiosInstance.get('/todos/1').then((res) => setTodo(res.data));
    axiosInstance.get('/users/1').then((res) => setUser(res.data));
  }, []);
  return (
    <>
      <p>title: {todo?.title}</p>
      <p>username: {user?.username}</p>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;

axiosInstance.ts:
import axios from 'axios';

export const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com',
});

main.tsx:
import { StrictMode } from 'react';
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './App.tsx';
import { axiosInstance } from './axiosInstance';
import mocks from './mocks';

if (import.meta.env.MODE === 'development') {
  console.log('setup mock');
  const MockAdapter = (await import('axios-mock-adapter')).default;
  const mock = new MockAdapter(axiosInstance);
  mocks.todosAPI(mock);
  mocks.usersAPI(mock);
}

createRoot(document.getElementById('root')!).render(
  <StrictMode>
    <App />
  </StrictMode>
);

./mocks/todos.ts:
import MockAdapter from 'axios-mock-adapter';

export const todosAPI = (mock: MockAdapter) => {
  mock.onGet('/todos/1').reply(200, {
    userId: 1,
    id: 1,
    title: 'fake todo title 1',
    completed: false,
  });
};

./mocks/users.ts:
import MockAdapter from 'axios-mock-adapter';

export const usersAPI = (mock: MockAdapter) => {
  mock.onGet('/users/1').reply(200, {
    id: 1,
    name: 'fake name',
    username: 'fake username',
    email: 'fake@april.biz',
  });
};

stackblitz
